# C++ Codeblocks compiling problem any solutuion?

Tags: c++, usb, codeblocks

[This what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkkJN.png) 
I'm having problems while compiling C++ codes on Code::blocks 17.12, on console application mode, when I run the Code saved on my hard disk, it runs without any flaw, but when I try to run the same code saved on my USB drive, it doesn't compile at all. Same case even with the hello world code.

My USB drive is totally fine and working fine. I tried the same thing with a different USB drive but same thing occurs. I tried long formatting my USB drive, checked for virus and all, but nothing seems to troubleshoot the problem.

The console just says "Process returned 4258096 (0x40F930)"

The Image above shows everything.

So any suggestion on your end would be really helpful. TIA

Comment: Somewhere Code::Blocks is going to show you the full build output. Find it, copy it, and paste it into your question. There are a few people who know what that error code means, but they are probably the folk who wrote the compiler. Significantly more people will be able to help you with the full error message.

Comment: I added an image of whats exactly happening

Comment: Your project folder and the CodeBlocks project file (*.cbp) are on USB drive or only the source code?

Comment: I've just created a new console project and saved on USB key. It's just an Hello world program. After compiling it, the program run without problem. I'm using CodeBlocks last nightly build with GCC  9.1